# Websocket makes server slow down download speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, websocket

I developed a websocket on server & client machines using Microsoft websocket.

Clients upload and download bookings with the server if there is any change from both sides. It is a real time communication between clients and server using Microsoft websocket.

It works fine with a few clients only. However, when I set up for around 100 clients. it makes download speeds of the server slow down. Normally, the internet speed of the server is around 900 Mbps and it drops to 50Mbps.

I configured websocket on IIS.  I checked on IIS, worker processes use too much CPU and bandwidth, CPU sometimes up to 100%.

How can I avoid this performance degradation?

Here is the sample of my code

```
public class booking : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new MicrosoftWebsockets());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MicrosoftWebsockets.WriteErrorWebSocket(e.Message, tillNumber);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public class MicrosoftWebsockets : WebSocketHandler
{
    private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();

    public string businessid;

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        try
        {
           ..............
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogError(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                ReceiveMessage(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogError(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public void ReceiveMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message);

            var s = json.method;

            if (s == "updatechanged")
            {
                updatechanged(this.businessid, json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogError(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task updatechanged(string businessid, dynamic json, string message)
    {
        List<Appointments> appts = DataHelper.ConvertJonToAppointmentList(businessid, message);
       
        if (appts != null && appts.Count > 0)
        {
            var resltList = await UpdateAppointment(businessid, appts);
            JArray props = new JArray();
            if (resltList != null && resltList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in resltList)
                {
                    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
                    props.Add(output);
                }

                JObject joe = new JObject();
                joe["jsonrpc"] = "2.0";
                joe["id"] = json.id;
                joe["method"] = "serverreturnappointment";
                joe.Add(new JProperty("params", props));

                string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joe);
                clients.SingleOrDefault(r => ((MicrosoftWebsockets)r).businessid == this.businessid).Send(result);              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a single thing called "Microsoft websocket" but a lot, so you should edit your question and be more specific. Ideally you need to share the actual code, as nobody can guess that out from a few words.

Comment: Many factors may affect Internet speed. Antivirus software on the client and server, switch settings, the speed at which the server reads data from the database, and the stability of the network.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, Bruce Zhang, I have edited my post with a sample of the code. Would you give me any suggestions?  
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure from where you copied the relevant code, but the classes used indicate that you are using the legacy ASP.NET 4.x on .NET Framework project type and the relevant things haven't been updated for more than 5 years. Thus, it is not likely to be worth the while to continue on this direction. You should check out ASP.NET Core instead.

Comment: Can you explain how you are measuring the download speeds? On average, how many socket messages does each client send per second? Can you replicate the performance issue with a handful of clients sending lots of messages?

Comment: @Alan I used speedtest.net to measure internet speed. Clients send a message to the server to request the server to send back all appointments. Clients also send new appointments to the server and update back to clients status. I think websocket is using all bandwidth and cpu (CPU sometimes upto 100%).